# UITableViewCell with UIImageView losing animation (iOS 5 bug?)

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, animation, ios5

This worked fine for me up until now - but in iOS 5, when I have an imageView on a regular UITableViewCell on a grouped tableview, and set the table from editing to NOT editing, the animation is lost and the text and image view just snap back into place instead of sliding. I am not reloading anything - I stripped my code down to almost nothing to solve this before I thought of simply commenting out the line where I say

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

and then everything worked fine. Is this a bug in iOS 5?

EDIT: So far, I think this is a problem with the UIImageView for the delivered tableview cells. It seems like the set-not-editing animation, for custom cells and UITableViewCell WITHOUT imageView is okay. I'd love to find a way to get around this, it makes things look unprofessional.

Below is my code for the part of the grouped tableview I am speaking of, this is part of cellforrowatindexPath:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemDetailDefaultCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
                cell.backgroundColor = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultCellBackgroundColor];

                cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);

                cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                cell.detailTextLabel.font = detailTextLabelFont;
                cell.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
                cell.detailTextLabel.minimumFontSize = DETAIL_TEXT_LABEL_MINIMUM_FONT_SIZE;

                cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultDetailTextColor];
                cell.detailTextLabel.shadowColor = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultDetailShadowColor];
                cell.detailTextLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
            }
            else {
                UIView* subview;
                while ((subview = [[[cell contentView] subviews] lastObject]) != nil)
                    [subview removeFromSuperview];
                cell.textLabel.text = nil;
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultCellSelectionStyle];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.accessoryView = nil;
            cell.editingAccessoryView = nil;

            cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
            cell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;

            cell.textLabel.textColor = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultMainTextColor];
            cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [[UIApplication sharedDelegate] defaultMainShadowColor];
            cell.textLabel.font = textLabelFont;
            cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            cell.textLabel.minimumFontSize = TEXT_LABEL_MINIMUM_FONT_SIZE;

            [(UACellBackgroundView *)cell.backgroundView setHeader:NO];
            if (row < itemsCount) {
                [(UACellBackgroundView *)cell.backgroundView setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle];
            }
            else {//row == items.count
                if (self.editing) {
                    [(UACellBackgroundView *)cell.backgroundView setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionMiddle];
                }
                else {
                    [(UACellBackgroundView *)cell.backgroundView setPosition:UACellBackgroundViewPositionBottom];
                }
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = item.name;
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"status1.png"];
return cell;
```

Comment: can you provide some more code of this class, or create new project and test only imageView in that

Answer (score 0):

Are you entering edit mode using this method

`[myTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];`

Also, if you are reloading the data, that will cancel the animation as well.

Comment: Yes, using that method. Not reloading the tableview, as I know that cancels the animation (see original question).